# Can't Autowired Service in AbstractJExcelView

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I try Autowired My Service in class who extends AbstractJExcelView but is always null.
I'm guess i can solve this problem change Dependency Injection with Annotation to xml configuration and inject manual component.

Controller

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("user")
public class UserController {
 @RequestMapping(value="/exportExel", method = RequestMethod.GET)
            public ModelAndView getExelView(@ModelAttribute User user){

    return new ModelAndView("ExelUserView","UserList",
            user);
   }
 }
```

Service

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImp implements UserService {

@Override
public String getAllFood(User user) {     //I Want Get All Element from model User 
                                         who contains Arrays String
    String backValue = "";              
    for(String s : user.getFavFood()){
        backValue +=s;
        backValue +=",";
    }

    return backValue;
}

}
```

And ExelView

```
public class ExelView extends AbstractJExcelView {

private UserServiceImp userService = new UserServiceImp();    // I solve my problem that 
                                                              //but in my controller i use Autowired Interface Service
                                                              // so i dont think its good solution

@Override
protected void buildExcelDocument(Map<String, Object> model,
        WritableWorkbook workbook, HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

    WritableSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("User Response", 0);
    setExelHead(sheet);

    User listUser = (User)model.get("UserList");
    setExelRows(sheet, listUser);

}



public void setExelRows(WritableSheet sheet,User listUser) throws RowsExceededException, WriteException{

    sheet.addCell(new Label(4, 1, userService.getAllFood(listUser))); 
}
}
```

And User Model

```
public class User implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private String[] favFood;

public String[] getFavFood() {  //I want View Arrays in Exel in one Cell
    return favFood;
}
public void setFavFood(String[] favFood) {
    this.favFood = favFood;
}
}
```

in xml i use

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.dinor913.example" />  // I guess delete auto    scan component and inject Manual all Controller and Service and this should work then

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.XmlViewResolver">
    <property name="location">
         <value>
             /WEB-INF/xml-views/document-views.xml
         </value>    
    </property>
    <property name="order" value="0"/>
</bean>
```

and document-views.xml

```
<bean name="ExelUserView"
  class="com.dinor913.example.businnes.ExelView" >
</bean>
```

UPDATE SOLVE!

I Added to document-views.xml

```
<context:annotation-config base-package="com.dinor913.example" />
```

So i understand when i create XmlViewResolver i also create new ApplicationContext for XmlViewResolver and context:annotation-config add @Autowired UserService to DispatcherServlet.

Thx For help.

I Just Start Learn Spring a few days ago

Sorry for my terrible english i hope you understand what i mean.....

Answer (score 0):

Change `private UserServiceImp userService = new UserServiceImp();` to:

```
@Autowired
private UserServiceImp userService
```

This should work. If not post the errormessage and the stacktrace.

Comment: I got Error NullPointerException , check in System.out and userService is null,i Inject ExelView in servlet-context so it's not autoscaning this class

Comment: What is the ExcelView? Is that your controller? If yes you need to at the @Controller annotation to it? If not how you instanciate the class?

Comment: Try to add the bean `ExelUserView` to  the xml file wich contains the `component-scan`